# In a foreign language, should my Action Types be translated?

Tags: action, facebook-opengraph

I am using this tutorial: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/

And I now need to define an action type. My website is in portuguese.

Should I use "read" anyways and Facebook will automatically translate it correctly, or should I use "ler" (which is portuguese for read) and then configure all the past tenses?

Comment: have you any update on this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create objects and actions in default English, then use translation tool to translate your objects and actions to other languages.

Official blog post:
http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/605/